# Add a single empty line as the last line in the code - clang-format

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I am using the clang-format extension in vscode to format my C++ code. I'm looking for a configuration that would add a single empty line as the last line in the code but, so far, I haven't found anything.

If I have

```c
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string s = "asfasdf";
  cout << "Type IIanything: ";
  // cin >> s;
  for (int i = s.length() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    cout << s[i];
  }
  cout << endl;
  cout << "NOT using build 2" << endl;
}
---empty line1---
---empty line2---
---empty line3---
```

then, when I save, the empty line 2 and 3 rows are gone and only 1 is left. This is fine for me. But if none of 1, 2 and 3 were there and I hit save, the closing brace is the last line in the code. What can I do to add an empty line after the closing brace in such a situation?

Answer (score 14):

Adding the following two entries to your `settings.json` should fix it:

```json
{
    "files.insertFinalNewline": true,
    "files.trimFinalNewlines": true
}
```

This will cause VS Code to either insert a final newline if none is present, or trim multiple final newlines so only one is present.

Comment: Thanks. It does what I was looking for. Is there also a clang-format specific solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of such an option for clang.

Comment: I would also like to know if there's a clang-format specific solution. I'm in an environment where I can't use VS Code.

Answer (score 6):

clang-format 16 now added an option for this: https://releases.llvm.org/16.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#insertnewlineateof

Add following entry in .clang-format will make clang-format to ensure there's one empty line (it will trim extra empty lines anyway):

```yaml
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
```

Comment: Enabling `InsertNewlineAtEOF` in .clang-format does not work for me. As the OP describes, it clears any extra new lines, but if there isn't one (or more) to begin with (e.g. if file ends with `}` not `\n`) clang-format will not insert the new line

Comment: @Braden, works for me.  What version of clang-format are you using?

Comment: @DanielWalker I'm not sure actually... I think my issues might be deeper and this not working properly might be a byproduct since I cannot run clang-format directly from the terminal—just says `zsh: command not found: clang-format`. I only use clang-format via 'format on save' in VSCode and a .clang-format file with clang installed via Xcode command line tools. My `clang --version` output is `Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.1.0.2.5)`.